# Unique messages for users based on username in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs. In visual studio MVC framework, it is possible to create roles and even display certain parts of the page or messages based on username. How can I do the same in nodejs? I have a login page on which I want to display for example,
`"You like cats" for username abcd` or 
`"You like dogs" for username efgh` or
`"You're not an animal person" for all other users`.

I know roles would work, but here instead of roles, I want this based on username. Is this even possible?

Server side login part:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'),
   function(req, res) {
   res.redirect('/home');
});
```

script to connect to HTML page

```
function loginUser() {
    var username = document.getElementsByClassName("username");
    var password = document.getElementsByClassName("password");

    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/login",
        method: "post",
        data: {
            username: username[0].value,
            password: password[0].value
        }
    }).success(function(response) {
        window.location.assign("/home");
    }).error(function(response) {
        alert("Incorrect username or password!");
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're currently working with?

Comment: Regardig your request to create 'roles', I can suggest using passport.js  for user management in Node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into using a templating language (such as [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)). Then instead of serving up static pages, you could render the template with whatever user-specific information you want.

It looks like you're using Express. If so, maybe take a look at [this](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) guide on using template engines with express.

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for. Jade seems to have been replaced by pug to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your questions appears to be how to access the post variables from a request.

Try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

With example:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// create application/json parser 
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser 
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// POST /login gets urlencoded bodies 
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
})
```